# What does the GEOS LineString "normalize()" routine really do?

Tags: linestring, geos, normalize

What does the GEOS LineString "normalize()" routine really do?

GEOS has virtual void geos::geom::LineString::normalize() with the documentation:

> A normalized linestring has the first point which is not equal to it's reflected point less than the reflected point.

Ignoring the "it's" typo, I still can't figure out what this really means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i can understand it sorts (very naively) the nodes firstly by x, if x are equal then by y.

https://github.com/libgeos/libgeos/blob/ea82e6058d43138810ce0a2787ba57c98a630dbf/src/geom/LineString.cpp#L330

CompareTo: https://github.com/libgeos/libgeos/blob/ea82e6058d43138810ce0a2787ba57c98a630dbf/include/geos/geom/Coordinate.inl#L64

reverse: https://github.com/libgeos/libgeos/blob/ea82e6058d43138810ce0a2787ba57c98a630dbf/src/geom/CoordinateSequence.cpp#L160

Comment: I think I agree. But, I keep telling myself that _can't_ be it because I can't think of an application of that sort on a LineString. (I _can_ see cases for "normalizting" a collection of points.) Without that, it sounds more like a bug than a feature. Probably just a hang-up on my part.

Comment: I cannot say with certain, I didn't find any references where that method was used. The maintainers might be able to provide you an explanation why is there.